# Dispatching an action in a specific component based on a reducer state change

Tags: reactjs, redux

In redux I want to show a modal if a specific reducer state changes. It is only relevant if the user is viewing a specific component. I used the container's mapDispatchToProps (publishState comes from a reducer):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {

    const {dispatch} = dispatchProps;
    const {appType, publishState, publishStages} = stateProps;
    const isWebsite = (appType !== 'MOBILE');

    switch (publishState.stage) {
        case publishStages.GENERATING_BUILDREQUEST:
        case publishStages.WAITING:
        case publishStages.WORKING:
        case publishStages.UPLOADING:
            dispatch(showModal(modalTypes.PUBLISH_MODAL, {isWebsite}));
            break;

        case publishStages.COMPLETED:
            dispatch(showModal(modalTypes.PUBLISH_SUCCESS_MODAL, {isWebsite}));
            break;

        case publishStages.ERROR:
            dispatch(showModal(modalTypes.PUBLISH_FAILURE_MODAL, {isWebsite}));
            break;

        default:
            dispatch(closeModal());
    }

    return {...
```

However this doesn't feel elegant as one wouldn't expect a mapping function to tweak state. Any ideas how to properly achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't indeed call dispatch in the mapDispatchToProps function. This function should be "pure" and just return a mapping without any side effect.

Since you know what action should trigger the modal ie. when `publicStages` is set to a particular value, I would suggest taking care of changing the state in 2 possible ways:

1. You can do this in the reducer. When you change `publicStages`, the reducer also has access to the modal state, and changes it too.
2. In the action. In the action that changes PublicStages, call the action to open/close the modal depending on what you do with `publicStages`. Be mindful that calling dispatch is supposed to be async.  In this case, you also need to dispatch from the action, so you have to pass the dispatch function down to the action.

---

EDIT: following the discussion in the comments - and for completeness - if the modal is displayed only as part of one visual component, you could also store its `open/closed` state in the component itself and manage it in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate`. An interesting read about that from Redux's creator Dan Abramov is [You Might Not Need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.ixbmaujly)

Comment: The thing is I only want the modal to be seen when a specific component is visible. Perhaps I can use your suggested method 2 with componentDidMount / componentWillUnmount to tweak a isModalVisible reducer parameters.

Comment: What you could also do, if the modal is dependent only on the component, is to manage its open/close state in the component itself instead of involving redux. Redux represents the state of the app, you can consider that the modal is just some part of the component and has nothing to do with the redux state. Sometimes this kind of simple fix makes the application way simpler to understand and reason about.